# Angular 2: Can I dynamically set the value for template reference variable?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `angular2-collapsible` to generate a table where each row can be expanded for detailed data. So my approach was to use `*ngFor` to loop through a list and generate each row and each corresponding detail.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let adData of adDataList; let i = index">
  <collapsible-table-row [detail]="adDataDetailNameList[i]">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </collapsible-table-row>

  <collapsible-table-row-detail #{{ adDataDetailNameList[i] }}>  <----This doesn't work
    <div>
      testing...
    </div>
  </collapsible-table-row-detail>
</ng-container>
```

Below is the demo code in `angular2-collapsible`:

```
<collapsible-table [type]="'accordion'" bordered>
  <thead>
    <collapsible-table-row>
      <th>Col #1</th>
      <th>Col #2</th>
      <th>Col #3</th>
    </collapsible-table-row>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <collapsible-table-row [detail]="detail1">  <----Assign 'detail1'
      <td>Cell(0,0)</td>
      <td>Cell(0,1)</td>
      <td>Cell(0,2)</td>
    </collapsible-table-row>
    <collapsible-table-row-detail #detail1>  <----Refer to 'detail1'
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td width="75%">Row #1 Detail #1</td>
          <td>Row #1 Detail #2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </collapsible-table-row-detail>
  </tbody>
</collapsible-table>
```

So the way that `row-detail` interact with `row` is by template reference variable, it seems. Since I am using `*ngFor` to generate these rows, I wonder if there is a way to assign template reference variables dynamically. If it is impossible (since I read somewhere that template reference variable is supposed to be static), is there any work-around for this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do anything like that